# Qt Syntax conversion from C++ to PyQt

Tags: python, c++, pyqt, pyside

I am trying to rewrite some PyQt C++ code in python.
I have done this type of syntax conversion many times, but not with a subclass example such as this.  This C++ code is intended to allow you to add comboboxes to a QTableWidget header to act similar to Excel header filters.
I can convert most of the logic, but I need help with the subclass syntax in python for this example.  Any help is appreciated.

```
MyHorizontalHeader(QWidget *parent = 0) : QHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal, parent)
{
     connect(this, SIGNAL(sectionResized(int, int, int)), this, 
             SLOT(handleSectionResized(int)));
     connect(this, SIGNAL(sectionMoved(int, int, int)), this, 
             SLOT(handleSectionMoved(int, int, int)));
     setMovable(true);
}

void showEvent(QShowEvent *e)
{
    for (int i=0;i<count();i++) {
       if (!boxes[i]) {
          QComboBox *box = new QComboBox(this);
          boxes[i] = box;
       }
       boxes[i]->setGeometry(sectionViewportPosition(i), 0, 
                                sectionSize(i) - 5, height());
       boxes[i]->show();
    }
    QHeaderView::showEvent(e);
 }

void handleSectionResized(int i)
{
    for (int j=visualIndex(i);j<count();j++) {
        int logical = logicalIndex(j);
        boxes[logical]->setGeometry(sectionViewportPosition(logical), 0, 
                                       sectionSize(logical) - 5, height());
    }
}

void handleSectionMoved(int logical, int oldVisualIndex, int newVisualIndex)
{
    for (int i=qMin(oldVisualIndex, newVisualIndex);i<count();i++){
        int logical = logicalIndex(i);
        boxes[logical]->setGeometry(sectionViewportPosition(logical), 0, 
                                       sectionSize(logical) - 5, height());
    }
}

void scrollContentsBy(int dx, int dy)
{
   QTableWidget::scrollContentsBy(dx, dy);
   if (dx != 0)
      horizHeader->fixComboPositions();
}

void fixComboPositions()
{
    for (int i=0;i<count();i++)
        boxes[i]->setGeometry(sectionViewportPosition(i), 0, 
                                 sectionSize(i) - 5, height());
}
```

This example source code originally comes from http://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/09/28/qt-support-weekly-27-widgets-on-a-header/

I hope to eventually create a custom subclass that I can promote for my QTableWidgets in "Qt Designer", whereby I can have custom QTableWidget QHeaderView with combobox filters.

Comment: Can you port everything you *do* understand first, so that it's easier to see which specific parts you are having problerms with?

Comment: This is the line I am having trouble with... MyHorizontalHeader(QWidget *parent = 0) : QHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal, parent)

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing in PyQt/PySide starts like this:

```
class MyHorizontalHeader(QHeaderView): 

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyHorizontalHeader, self).__init__(Qt.Horizontal, parent)

    def otherMethod(self):
        ...
    ...
```

The first line defines the name of the class and the potential inheritance.

The `__init__` method is called when creating an instance of the class. It always needs to call the `__init__` method of the class it inherits from (this is specific of PyQt/PySide), which is done with `super`.